# Table of Build-in Functions by Crystal Report Version

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there some kind of Build-in function comparison table where I can easily see which version supports which Build-in function?

The reason I am asking is: I was having trouble with a Crystal Report document. In the end, the problem was that I'm using Version 11 (aka XI) on the development server and the productive server has Version 9. Version 11 supports the build-in Function "RoundUp(...)" and apparently Version 9 doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a table which compare Build-in functions next to each other. This information might still be usfull:

- [Crystal 10: Formula Language Reference (PDF)](http://www.crystalbook.com/crtcr/extras/10/AppA.pdf)
- [Crystal Reports for Rational Application Developer: Functions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/topic/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic506.html)

I wish I would have found some older References. :P